# Ajax Call Success Function Firing Twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that gets fired after the onkeyup event of an input. Once 8 numbers have been entered, it makes a call.

If the call was successful, it adds a new row to a table.

The problem is that it's adding 2 rows. The ajax call if being fired twice as well. If I have the debugger is running, it only adds 1 row. If have an alert for when the row is added, it only adds 1 row. If I don't have the debugger or the alert, it adds 2 . Not sure why.

The input:

```
<input style="width:100px" type="text" id="account0" maxlength="8" onkeyup="getAccount(this);" />
```

The function, addrow is being fired twice (unless I'm debugging or put in a pop-up). The addrow function contains no loops, just adds a row to an HTML table. The variable i remains the same for both calls, it does not get incremented:

```
function getAccount(val) {
        var account = val.value;
        if (account.length == 8) {
            var i = parseInt(val.id.replace("account", ""));
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/123/AccountSelect?account=" + account,
                dataType: 'json',
                ContentType: "application/json, charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (data) {
                        //create new row for next account if needed
                        addRow(i + 1, data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    showModal(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Again, it only does this if there's no debugger running (of course) or no pop-up to interrupt the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked. I used a boolean to only allow the row to be added once, then used the onmouseup event of the newly created input in the new row to reset the boolean to allow for other rows to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `async: false` as following:

```
function getAccount(val) {
    var account = val.value;
    if (account.length == 8) {
        var i = parseInt(val.id.replace("account", ""));
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/123/AccountSelect?account=" + account,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            ContentType: "application/json, charset=UTF-8",
            success: function (data) {
                    //create new row for next account if needed
                    addRow(i + 1, data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                showModal(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have, and unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Also using async: false in production code is not something I like doing.

Comment: so strange... let me try again

Comment: or I think you can use any boolean variable, for ex, row_added. it would be false at first, and you will change that value when adding row.

Comment: I think it's the fastest solution to solve your problem right now.

Comment: In theory yes a boolean should work, but I also tried that and it did not.

Comment: sorry, but I can't guess the reason with these msgs only... :(

Comment: The problem with the boolean approach is multiple rows need to be added in 1 session, so it needs to be reset for the next one, which then allows for the duplicate. Thanks for helping

Comment: Here's what worked. I used a boolean to only allow the row to be added once, then used the onmouseup of the newly created input in the new row to reset the boolean. Seems to be doing what I need. Thanks again